# GitHub actions - get absolute path to working directory

Tags: github-actions

In Maven, I need to provide absolute path to a directory in my project. How can I get absolute path to the directory GitHub action is running in?

Comment: Did you try using the [$GITHUB_WORKSPACE](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/environment-variables) env var?

Comment: Yes, but some reason empty string is passed in this case

-DSteam.path=${{ env.GITHUB_WORKSPACE }}/lib

Comment: Did you use the `checkout/actions` on your workflow before accessing the  `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE`? Did you try to save the path as local variable before using it in your workflow? (If yes, could you edit your question with your workflow to see how you did it?)

Comment: For some reason using ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE} helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As pointed out by @soltex, [`${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables#default-environment-variables) points to the checkout directory.

Answer (score 16):

In addition to the environment variable described by [@Evgeny Bovykin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69813340/840714), you can also use the [`${{ ...}}` syntax](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/1794#issuecomment-707217728) with:

```
${{ github.workspace }}
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/issues/1794#issuecomment-707217728).

Comment: This was the one that worked for me. Think it might have something to do with the above answer only working inside an actual `run:` script whereas yours workers even outside of an actual workflow.